# TFS 2015 best practices

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have been doing a bit of research on how to best configure our environment.  I cannot seem to get a good answer so here's the setup:

- 3 programmers
- each working on the same project/solution
- the solution consists of 200+ small classes/modules that we maintain and are called using "invoke" by class name (and this will continue to grow)

The problems have been that

- I cannot pull the solution from TFS because I don't want to inherit errors that the other developers are working on
- If I do decide to do a recursive "Get Latest" it seems to skip some files.  It just not reliable
- Pulling latest (without the solution) will pull new classes but they are not added to my solution unless I add them by hand.   I know this is related to the previous comment about pulling the solution.

Can anyone lay out the best and most reliable way of using TFS in this environment?   We always have to triple check everything before going live to make sure nothing was left out and that we have all the appropriate latest versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot pull the solution from TFS because I don't want to inherit errors that the other developers are working on

Are you using Git version control or TFS version control?  There are several way to avoid errors from other developers.

If using Git, you can create a Develop branch that everyone checks their code into.  Then, only when the code in that branch has been tested, you merge it into the Master branch.  You can always Get from the Master branch to get the latest stable copy.

If you want even more protection of the Master branch, you can require developers to create their own Fork of the Develop branch.  They check their changes into their own Fork, and then create a Pull Request to ask everyone to test their changes.  Only when a Lead Developer approves, that lead can merge their Pull Request into the Develop branch.  Which can then be tested and merged to Master.

With TFS Version Control, you can have developers Shelve their changes until they are tested.  Then check-in once tested.

> If I do decide to do a recursive "Get Latest" it seems to skip some files. It just not reliable

Have you tried using "Get Specific Version"?  Then check both of the Overwrite boxes.

> Pulling latest (without the solution) will pull new classes but they are not added to my solution unless I add them by hand. I know this is related to the previous comment about pulling the solution.

This issue should be solved by implementing the strategies laid out above.

Comment: Thanks Milke.  Let me decipher this :).  I think I see where you're going.